# How to resolve a variable's value inside an array in bash

Tags: shell-script, array, variable-substitution

I have a few files whose names I have assigned into variables. (There may be n number of files). Those variables are passed into an array. Now I want to print the names of the original files using that array.

Since there can be n number of files, I cannot make a static list of file names.
I need to make a tar of every file.
In one case, there can be only 1 file, in other, there can be 2 or 3 or 4 files. 
So I am creating a generic script for this purpose.

```
export count=2
testlist0=abc 
testlist1=notabc
declare -a testlist_array[$count]
for ((i=0;i<${count};i++));
do
  testlist_array[$i]=testlist$i
done
echo ${testlist_array[@]}
```

But it is not printing the file names abc not abc.

Comment: Change inside of loop to `var="testlist$i";testlist_array[$i]="${!var}"`

Comment: @123 would you like to convert your perfectly good comment into an Answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's a duplicate, can't be bothered finding it though.